# Can I use my Xbox One controller to play the PC versions of the Mass Effect games?

Tags: controllers, mass-effect-series

I asked [this question](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/259729/mass-effect-series-shall-i-start-from-the-beginning-for-better-understand/259742#259742) and based on the answer I decided to buy the entire trilogy.

However, I have one concern. I am a bit bored from using the keyboard + mouse and want to try the Xbox one controller. Of course I could just get the Xbox version but it is less private to the children. There seems to be some [mods](http://www.nexusmods.com/masseffect/mods/60/?) that allows the use of the Xbox 360 controller.

So I wonder if it would work with a Xbox One controller or if I need another mod to do this. Has anyone tried this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Today I installed the game with all DLCs plus the mod I mention in the question.

Yes, my Xbox One controller works perfectly with the mod. So this finally answers the question.

Answer (score 4):

I don't know about Mass Effect specifically, but from my experience, the Xbox One controller **works on all games** which support the Xbox 360 controller.

---

Keep in mind that games that support the Xbox 360 controller, but not the Xbox One controller, may ask you to press buttons that are not available on the Xbox One controller, such as <kbd>Start</kbd> and <kbd>Back</kbd>. The equivalent to <kbd>Start</kbd> is <kbd>Menu</kbd>, and the equivalent to <kbd>Back</kbd> is <kbd>View</kbd>.

Comment: Thanks for the help, especially `View` for `Back`.  I would think it is `B` otherwise.

Comment: One of the worst things you can do is "answer" a question by saying, "I don't know but here's an uninformed opinion." Please don't "answer" questions if you don't know the answer.

Comment: @MikeBethany. First of all, my answer is based on my experience with quite a lot of games, old and new, and they all behaved in the same way without any exception. This is called [**empirical evidence**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Empirical_evidence), not "uninformed opinion". Remember that you're always allowed to downvote an answer (welcome, even) if you think it is not useful. Whether years of experience is useful to you or not, that's for you to judge.

Comment: @Nolonar More accurately you're using [inductive reasoning](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inductive_reasoning). You are making a generalization based on past observations, e.g. "All swans are white because I've never seen a black swan." This is the weakest form of reasoning, you even admit you do not know, thus my criticism stands.

Answer (score 3):

If you're looking for official controller support, **none of the PC versions of the Mass Effect games have it**. You could probably use a third party program like [Joy2Key](http://joytokey.net/en/), but you would need to configure that yourself or download a profile someone else has made.

Answer (score 1):

If the PC recognizes the controller then sure, you'll be able to play it.

The mod you linked to improves the HUD while playing with the controller, but breaks it if you change to keyboard + mouse, as stated.

Comment: I confirmed that the Mass Effect 2 Demo version does not support Xbox 360 controller (and PC recognizes the controller, as the Steam big picture supports it). The full game might do though.

Comment: Not all games have controller support. Mass Effect is one of the ones that doesn't.

Comment: The mod site linked by OP specifies that the controller works on ME1, and the mod itself adds functionalities

Answer (score -4):

Xbox 1 and Win 10 pose serious problems for ME1. There are some good profile sites to program your controller but the trick is to get the Game to recognize your controller. NexusMods has an ME1Controller bypass that you can download and install that's fairly simple. Beware! It states right in the Mods description that It'll Break certain aspects of your game. Those aspects pertain to the level-up screen. Half of the screen is blank and it's the half that you'd need to see in order to make your level-up choices. Your other choice is to try and play with kb/m. I brought this oversight to the attention of the folks at EA and Bioware and the overall reaction from them was "Oh-Well!"

Comment: To be fair, developers are not going to rework games because unauthorized are failing to work.